# Gel electrophoresis bands

Tags: biotechnology, gel-electrophoresis, immunoglobin

Is there any way to calculate the number of bands formed due to sodium dodecyl sulphate-polyacrylamide gel electrophoresis for a particular compound of group of proteins? For example, how could I calculate the number of bad formed after electrophoresis of IgG (immunoglobulin G) under oxidizing or reducing conditions?

Comment: This sounds like a homework question, which are not allowed unless you show your attempt at the answer. Do you know what reducing conditions will do to a protein? Do you know the structure of immunoglobulins?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I think I figured out what was required. Immunoglobulins have 2 light chains and 2 heavy chains. So 2 distinct bands would be formed (the heavier one at the back and the lighter one in the front) I suppose.